# Bluetooth on win 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

i have no bluetooth button, anywhere, had it one time accidentally double clicked it. it disappeared again. yes ive checked every thing. devices, manager, options, control panel, even dug into system files. have spent hours on this. i found system files showing bluetooth but they all showed that they were stopped.    ??? pls, how do i get my bluetooth cause this is gonna drive me crazy til its fixed.

Comment: What model HP laptop do you have? When did this stop working? Did you upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 or did it come with Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound dumb, but, have you clicked the Windows icon and typed BLUETOOTH in?  It'll bring up a Bluetooth Settings option.  Click that.  Turn bluetooth on.  Once on, click the "More Bluetooth options" and check all three boxes (Discovery, Notifications, Show the Bluetooth icon). Also click the Hardware tab.  There may be several options inside the Devices box.  Select one and click Properties at bottom of box.  In properties box, select Power Management tab.  Make sure "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is NOT checked. Click OK.  Repeat for each of the items in the Devices section.

If you need to see if the actual service is stopped, click the Windows icon, type System Configuration.  On the Services tab, sort Service data by clicking the column header. Scroll down until you get to Bluetooth items and make sure the check box next to each is checked.  If not, check them, click  OK.  It'll prompt you to reboot your machine, so save/close any open apps and reboot.  See if that works.